# AdMob Ads not showing but test ads show (iOS)

Tags: ios, admob, app-store

It's been more than a month since I've created the ad units, however I've only been using the test ads when I ran on XCode. Recently, I've changed the test ads to real ads and submitted it to the App Store. When I downloaded the app, the real ads weren't showing. I'm planning to give it a couple hours as I heard that may be the case, however it seems like the app isn't requesting any real ads (shown from the admob app overview). However my app was able to successfully request the test ads.

Update: I've also heard that I needed to update my payment info, so I have done that. How should I be able to check whether my app is requesting ads properly now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ask the Admob support,
2. Sometimes there is a several hours lag before real ads start to show, after you publish your app,
3. Double check that all of your `app/banner IDs`, `GoogleService-Info.plist`, etc. are configured right.